# Field Not Recognized on AddAsync of SharePoint List Item

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

When I try to create a new list item with the basic calendar/list fields everything works perfectly.  However, when I try to do so with a "non-standard" field i.e. a field I added, I am getting a "field not recognized" error.

The field is clearly there! Is there some special way I need to populate these custom fields?

```
// get a specific list
ISiteListsCollectionPage list = await graphClient.Sites["root"].Lists.Request()
    .Filter($"DisplayName eq 'Outlook Integration'").GetAsync();

// create a dictionary of [calendar] list properties
Dictionary<string, object> props = new Dictionary<string, object>();

// populate properties, all of these work just fine
props.Add("Title", evt.Subject);
props.Add("Location", evt.Location?.DisplayName);
props.Add("EventDate", utcStart.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK"));
props.Add("EndDate", utcEnd.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK"));
props.Add("Description", Regex.Replace(evt.Body.Content, "<.*?>", String.Empty)); // remove HTML content

// populate custom properties
props.Add("ResourceID", evt.Id); // throws error: Field 'ResourceID' is not recognized

// create list item with our properties dictionary
var newItem = new ListItem
{
    Name = "My New Event",
    Fields = new FieldValueSet()
    {
        AdditionalData = props
    }
};

// call the service and get the result
var newListItem = await graphClient.Sites["root"].Lists[list[0].Id].Items.Request().AddAsync(newItem);
```

This is the complete list of fields on my list:

[image]

Here you can see the display name is "ResourceID" whereas the API name is "O365EventId." However, both result in the same error, "Field not recognized."

[image]

**Note:** ResourceID is one of the fields that I added. How can I set the value of this field via the Graph API?

Comment: What do you get if you request the list of fields for that list? A column has two values,  the `id` and display name, which often times are _not_ the same. If you look at the column itself, you might find it has a very different ID than `ResourceId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marc is right by saying in comment regarding column name, the provided screenshot displays `Column.displayName` which is

> The user-facing name of the column.

but what actually `FieldValueSet.AdditionalData` expects as a key is `Column.name` which is:

> The API-facing name of the column as it appears in the [fields](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/fieldvalueset) on a
>   listItem. For the user-facing name, see displayName.

In your case most likely `displayName` and `name` properties are different, you could verify it via following endpoint:
 `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/Outlook Integration/columns`

and that's the reason why this error occurs.

Via the Graph API client (C#), you can see a list of all columns for any given list like so:

```
// get specific list by name
ISiteListsCollectionPage list = await graphClient.Sites["root"].Lists.Request()
    .Filter($"DisplayName eq 'YOUR_LIST_NAME_HERE'").GetAsync();

// get columns and output them to the log as a serialized object
var listColumns = await graphClient.Sites["root"].Lists[list[0].Id].Columns.Request().GetAsync();
logger.LogInformation($"List Columns Object: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listColumns).ToString()}");
```

Comment: Thanks, Vadim.  The column name is actually "O365EventID" which I've also tried but the same error occurs.  This is evidenced by clicking the link in the screenshot above in which the URL reads, "&Field=O365EventID."  Is there any other reason why the API wouldn't be able to update this field?

Comment: Sorry, silly mistake...  I had "O365EventId" whereas it was expecting "O365Event**ID**."  I've updated your answer with a code sample.  Thanks for your help.